# How can I pass a pointer to an array using p/invoke in C#?

Tags: c#, c, api, pinvoke

Example C API signature:

`void Func(unsigned char* bytes);`

In C, when I want to pass a pointer to an array, I can do:

```
unsigned char* bytes = new unsigned char[1000];
Func(bytes); // call
```

How do I translate the above API to P/Invoke such that I can pass a pointer to C# byte array?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The easiest way to pass an array of bytes is to declare the parameter in your import statement as a byte array.

```
[DllImport EntryPoint="func" CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true]
public extern static void Func(byte[]);

byte[] ar = new byte[1000];
Func(ar);
```

You should also be able to declare the parameter as an IntPtr and Marshal the data manually.

```
[DllImport EntryPoint="func" CharSet=CharSet.Auto, SetLastError=true]
public extern static void Func(IntPtr p);

byte[] ar = new byte[1000];
IntPtr p = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(byte)) * ar.Length);
Marshal.Copy(ar, 0, p, ar.Length);
Func(p);
Marshal.FreeHGlobal(p);
```

Comment: why would the first approach work, and the second not work. This is what i'm facing on a windows phone app.

Comment: I know this post is a little old but `Marshal.SizeOf(object)` does not work with arrays. I am pretty sure you will get an exception if you pass it an array but I do not have VS open in front of me right now to try. To correctly determine the size of an array, for your example the code would be `Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(byte)) * ar.Length`.

Comment: Yes, you're right 9ee1.  Marshal.SizeOf can be used for a structure but not an array.  I've updated the example code accordingly.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You can use unsafe code:

```
unsafe 
{
     fixed(byte* pByte = byteArray)
     IntPtr intPtr = new IntPtr((void *) pByte);
     Func(intPtr);
}
```

If you need to use safe code, you can use a few tricks:

```
IntPtr intPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(byteArray));
Marshal.Copy(byteArray, 0, intPtr, Marshal.SizeOf(byteArray));

Func(intPtr);

Marshal.FreeHGlobal(intPtr);
```

However, the safe code is going to be slow IMHO.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the appropriate signature for the native function.

```
[System.Runtime.InteropServices.DllImportAttribute("<Unknown>", EntryPoint="Func")]
public static extern  void Func(System.IntPtr bytes) ;
```