# importing a c dll function into c#

Tags: c#, dll, import

I am trying to use a function in C# from an unmanged C dll.  I'm new to C# and am unsure if I'm doing this correctly.  The function in C looks something like this:

```
unsigned short Function(unsigned short, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned short*);


[DllImport("cDLLfile.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
private static extern short Function(ushort a, UInt32 b, UInt32 c, IntPtr buffer);
```

The buffer is an array something like

```
ushort[] = new ushort[7];
```

I fill the array then try to pass it to Function and am getting a error.  I know IntPtr is not right.  What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Can you post the error you are getting?

Comment: Seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/289076/how-can-i-pass-a-pointer-to-an-array-using-p-invoke-in-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should work with ushort[]

```
[DllImport("cDLLfile.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true) ]
private static extern short Function(ushort a, UInt32 b, UInt32 c, ushort[] buffer);
```

Comment: Avoid ExactSpelling, the C function is usually exported as _Function.  CallingConvention is required, Cdecl.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
extern short Function(ushort a, UInt32 b, UInt32 c, ushort[] buffer)
```

Comment: No, don't try that.  That will give a pointer-to-pointer (i.e. `ushort **`).

Answer (score 0):

[Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hk9wyw21%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) you will find details and sample code on how to marshal arrays.