# working with pointers from an ocx control in c# csharp

Tags: c#, .net, pointers, ocx

**Edit:**
I'm working with an ocx control in C#. This contrl has properties which contain the length of a data buffer and a pointer to that buffer. How can access/get/use that data with possibly a point in C#. I'm using Visual Studio 2008.

<strike>i work with .ocx control in c#. That .ocx have a properties which contains len of data buffer and pointer to data buffer. How i can get data, using that pointer in c#? I use VS C# 2008</strike>

Comment: It is all about Marshalling.  Could you please provide the C/Pascal definition of the function that you are calling.  From that I will provide you with the correct C# function definition

Comment: .ocx have function: Public Function WriteData(ByVal devIndex As Long, ByVal lpOutData As Long, ByVal cntData As Long) As Long. How can i call this method? Also ocx have: event Public Event DataArrival(ByVal devIndex As Long, ByVal lpDataBufer As Long, ByVal lenDataBufer As Long). In c# this event: private void AX_DataArrival(object sender, AxUSBBridge.__FT245R_DataArrivalEvent e), the e variable have devIndex, lenDataBufer, lpDataBufer properties.  lenDataBufer is size of buffer, lpDataBufer is pointer to data array. How to get buffer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't give exact details, so this is a guess based on your info. You can find an example [here](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/654578-hint-marshalling-byte-array-into-void-pointer). I'll quote (and simplify) the relevant parts:

```
// C/C++
int ncWrite(unsigned long DataSize, void* DataPtr)

// C#
[DllImport("Nican.dll")]
unsafe static extern int ncWrite(uint DataSize, byte[] DataPtr);

byte[] DataWrite = {0x23, 0x23, 0x30, 0x03, 0x78, 0xEC, 0xFF, 0xFF };
int status = ncWrite(Marshal.SizeOf(DataWrite), DataWrite);
```

EDIT: With your info:

```
// .ocx
Public Function WriteData(ByVal devIndex As Long, ByVal lpOutData As Long, ByVal cntData As Long) As Long

// C#
[DllImport("TheOcxControl.dll")]
static extern int WriteData(int index, byte[] outputData, int outputDataLength);

byte[] DataToWrite = {0x23, 0x23, 0x30, 0x03, 0x78, 0xEC, 0xFF, 0xFF };
int status = WriteData(index, DataToWrite, Marshal.SizeOf(DataToWrite));
```

As for the arrival event:

```
// the e variable have devIndex, lenDataBufer, lpDataBufer properties.
// lenDataBufer is size of buffer, lpDataBufer is pointer to data array.
byte[] destination;
Marshal.Copy(lpDataBufer, destination, 0, lenDataBufer);
```

Comment: Good inference.  But we do not know if the buffer is Input or Output.

Comment: how can i Use DllImport if i use ocx? i add that on my toolbox and drop on form, and all import took place automatically? for arrival event error: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(int[], int, System.IntPtr, int)' has some invalid arguments. Have you a good article about Marshaling and IntPtr in c#?

Comment: Where did you get the "public function..." part? I haven't used ocx controls, so I don't know how it shows up in your project. As for the Marshal.Copy(), I assumed you would use this overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631.aspx

Answer (score 0):

check this one out. [How can I pass a pointer to an array using p/invoke in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289076/how-can-i-pass-a-pointer-to-an-array-using-p-invoke-in-c)