# How to call an ActiveX function with char * parameter in C#

Tags: c#, c++, activex, atl

I have this c++ function :

```
unsigned int ReadUserMemory( unsigned char *lpBuffer, unsigned int iAddress, unsigned int nNumberOfByte );
```

Which reads `nNumberOfByte` bytes from `iAddress` of a memory and places it in `lpBuffer`.
I created an ATL Object for it( Going to be used in C# ) with this interface :

```
[id(6), helpstring("method ReadUserMemory")] HRESULT ReadUserMemory(BYTE* lpBuffer, [in] ULONG iAddress, [in] ULONG nNumberOfByte, [out,retval] ULONG* result);
```

I'm neither C# programmer nor experienced ATL programmer! Now I'm going to test this function in C# with this code :

```
byte [] b = new byte[100];
axObj.ReadUserMemory(b, 0, 100);
```

But apparently this code is wrong. How to call this method? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is there a reason that you are using COM instead of C++ interop. The latter is actually far easier.

Comment: @PeterR ~> Just because my boss wants ! He wants to use this object without any problem in other languages !

Comment: You should also consider using [Marshal.Copy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146631%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) Method (IntPtr, Byte[], Int32, Int32). It's built into .NET and does what your function seems to do.

Comment: @Tom Blodget if this works (and it looks like it should) it could be a much better way forward

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think Peter R has a very valid point, in that using COM is complicated, because it requires learning COM as well as C++ and C#, as you've discovered. C++ interop is another option, but that also requires learning a third technology, called C++/CLI, which is *probably* a better fit than COM, but can still be problematic. Both COM and C++/CLI are quite big, complicated beasts, so you might be better off just declaring the C function you need in a dll and using P/Invoke, see e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164123.aspx. If so, the magic you want can be found in [How can I pass a pointer to an array using p/invoke in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/289076/how-can-i-pass-a-pointer-to-an-array-using-p-invoke-in-c).

Assuming you want to continue down the COM route, I had a play around with it, and to me it looks like you need to get something that is going to work via the type library that is embedded in the COM dll. In short, I couldn't make the COM interop work with `unsigned char *lpBuffer`, although perhaps someone else can! The type-library friendly type to use is a SAFEARRAY, which is essentially the way that VB likes to see arrays.

In this case, your idl becomes

```
[id(1)] HRESULT ReadUserMemory([out] SAFEARRAY(byte)* buffer, [in] ULONG iAddress, [in] ULONG nNumberOfByte, [out,retval] ULONG* result);
```

Your C++ implementation looks like something like this

```
STDMETHODIMP CObj::ReadUserMemory(SAFEARRAY ** pBuffer, ULONG iAddress, ULONG nNumberOfByte, ULONG* result)
{
    if (pBuffer== nullptr)
        return E_POINTER;

    SAFEARRAY*& psa = *pBuffer;
    SAFEARRAYBOUND rgsabound[1];
    rgsabound[0].lLbound = 0;
    rgsabound[0].cElements = nNumberOfByte;
    psa = SafeArrayCreate(VT_UI1, 1, rgsabound);
    if(psa == NULL)
        return E_OUTOFMEMORY;

    void* data = nullptr;
    SafeArrayAccessData(psa, &data);
    for(int i=0; i<nNumberOfByte; ++i) {
        ((char*)data)[i] = (char)i;
    }
    SafeArrayUnaccessData(psa);

    return S_OK;
}
```

The `SafeArrayUnaccessData` should be called even if the code after the `SafeArrayAccessData` fails.

The C# client now looks like this, notably we have changed from `byte[]` to `System.Array`

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        RUMLib.IObj axObj = new RUMLib.Obj();
        Array a = null;
        axObj.ReadUserMemory(out a, 2, 6);
        for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; ++i)
        {
            Console.Write("{0},", a.GetValue(i));
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }
```

and the output of the program is

> 0,1,2,3,4,5,

Note that there will v likely be marshalling, i.e. copying of the data, as the data comes back from the SAFEARRAY to the C# array. This might be prohibitively costly for you, in which case suggest you go with C++/CLI or P/Invoke.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll check it as soon as I get home.